# How to pass break values to stat_contour by facet or group

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I am trying to use the ks library to calculate the 95% home range for groups within a data set. The problem is that the "break" values which define the cut-off for the 95% contours differ between groups. So far, I have been able to get my plots, but I have to manually add the break values for each group/level and I would really like to find a solution where I can create figures in ggplot where the break values are imported automatically.

```
require(ks)
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)

   # define the ks function to pass to a grouped_df 
ksFUN = function(data){

  H = Hpi(data[,c("x","y")], binned = TRUE) * 1

  fhata = kde(data[,c("x","y")], H = H, compute.cont = TRUE,
                  xmin = c(minX, minY), xmax = c(maxX, maxY))
  res95 = data.frame(HR = contourSizes(fhata, cont = 95, approx = TRUE))

  dimnames(fhata[['estimate']]) = list(fhata[["eval.points"]][[1]],
                                       fhata[["eval.points"]][[2]])
  dat = reshape2::melt(fhata[['estimate']])
  dat$breaks50 = fhata[["cont"]]["50%"]
  dat$breaks95 = fhata[["cont"]]["5%"]
  return(dat)
}
set.seed(100)


# create some data
df1 = data.frame(x = rnorm(100, 0, 5),
                 y = rnorm(100, 0, 5), 
                 Group = "Test1")
df2 = data.frame(x = rnorm(100, 10, 5),
                 y = rnorm(100, 10, 5), 
                 Group = "Test2")
df = rbind(df1, df2)

# Set the minimum and maximum x and y values outside 
# of the ksFUN to keep the data on the same scale
minX = min(df$x, na.rm = T); maxX = max(df$x, na.rm = T)
minY = min(df$y, na.rm = T); maxY = max(df$y, na.rm = T)

xx = df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  do(as.data.frame(ksFUN(.)))


# extract the break value for the 95% contour (home range) and 50% (core area)
breaks = xx %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarize(breaks95 = mean(breaks95),
            breaks50 = mean(breaks50))

breaks



# The only way I have been able to add the breaks is to manually add them

ggplot(data = xx, aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = Group)) +
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, col = Group)) +
  stat_contour(data = xx[xx$Group == "Test1",], aes(z = value),
                         breaks = 0.000587, alpha = 0.3, geom = "polygon") +
  stat_contour(data = xx[xx$Group == "Test2",], aes(z = value),
                         breaks = 0.000527, alpha = 0.3, geom = "polygon")
```

[image]

I would really like to find a solution where I don't have to explicitly pass the break values to the stat_contour functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a problem with using the `breaks` column in `breaks`? e.g.

```
# base plot
pl <- ggplot(data = xx, aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = Group)) +
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, col = Group))
groups <- unique(xx$Group)

# loop and add for each group
for(i in groups){
  pl <- pl + stat_contour(data = xx[xx$Group == i,], aes(z = value),
                          breaks = breaks[breaks$Group == i, ]$breaks, 
                          alpha = 0.3, geom = "polygon")
}
pl
```

I get some weird plots, at the edges, especially when I remove the `breaks` part from `stat_contour`, which leads me to think there might be a bug in `ksFUN`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much. this will definitely work. I think I found the issue with the contours getting cut-off. I set the xmin and xmax outside of ksFUN function to keep the groups on the same scale rather than having each group having its own scale.

Comment: this is actually brilliant, and a useful approach for many other facet specific stats or actions too - thanks Jonny!

Comment: the only thing I can't wrap my head around is how I can accomplish a common color scheme for all breaks, since they will be different across panels - any thoughts?

Comment: No worries :). You can set the colours before hand, either with standard or using hexcodes. First create a vector same length of groups e.g. `cols <- c("red", "yellow")`. Then in the `stat_contour` function add this argument at the end: `fill=cols[match(i, groups)]`

Comment: that doesn't quite work for my case, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78161961/how-to-do-group-wise-2d-density-quantile-plots-with-custom-function-and-consiste