# How to do group-wise 2d density quantile plots with custom function and consistent coloring?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Inspired by [this idea of creating quantile-specific contours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75629415/5238559)  that uses `geom_density2d_filled()`I wanted to achieve the same thing but for grouped data shown in a multi-panel plot with `facet_wrap()`.

Specifically, **my goal is to have a particular proportion of the points their respective quantile contour** - i.e., given the figure below, 25% of the red points in the yellow area, 50% in the green area, and so on. However, I can't get this to work properly with multiple groups within the same plot.

### starting point

```
library(MASS)
library(terra)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(cowplot)
library(viridis)

## custom density quantile function by Allan Cameron
density_quantiles <- function(x, y, quantiles, n_grid=500) {
  dens <- MASS::kde2d(x, y, n = n_grid)
  df   <- cbind(expand.grid(x = dens$x, y = dens$y), z = c(dens$z))
  r    <- terra::rast(df)
  ind  <- sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) cellFromXY(r, cbind(x[i], y[i])))
  ind  <- ind[order(-r[ind][[1]])]
  vals <- r[ind][[1]]
  ret  <- approx(seq_along(ind)/length(ind), vals, xout = quantiles)$y
  replace(ret, is.na(ret), 1)
}

## data
set.seed(4393)
dat <- data.table(diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ])+

## not correct
p1 = 
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y))  + 
  facet_wrap(~cut, ncol=3) +
  geom_density_2d_filled(breaks = density_quantiles(dat$x,dat$y, c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.95), 100)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d('Quantiles:', labels = scales::percent(qt[-1]), direction = -1) +
  geom_jitter(size=0.25, color="red", width=0.2) + 
  theme(legend.position = c(0.75,0.25))
```

[image]

This is not correct, since the breaks are calculated across all panels, but I don't know how to pass on the group subset to the custom function and thereby set group specific breaks. In the help for `geom_density2d_filled()` there is a cryptic statement for the `breaks` argument:

> - A function that takes the range of the data and binwidth as input and
>   returns breaks as output. A function can be created from a formula
>   (e.g. ~ fullseq(.x, .y)).

Does that mean I can somehow pass on the data subset created by `facet_wrap`to the custom function? This would be ideal!

### workaround 1

Of course I can just do separate figures, and while this seems clumsy and complicated, the countours are correct here:

```
## correct but clumsy / complicated
plist = list()
for(c in c("Fair", "Good", "Very Good", "Premium", "Ideal")){
  dat_sub = dat[cut==c,]
  plist[[c]] = ggplot(dat_sub, aes(x, y))  + ggtitle(c) + coord_fixed() + 
    geom_density_2d_filled(breaks = density_quantiles(dat_sub$x,dat_sub$y, c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.95), 100)) +
    scale_fill_viridis_d('Quantiles:', labels = scales::percent(qt[-1]), direction = -1) +
    geom_jitter(size=0.25, color="red", width=0.2) + 
    theme(legend.position = "none")
}
pgrid = cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = plist, ncol=5)
leg = cowplot::get_plot_component(p1, "guide-box", return_all = TRUE)[[3]]
p2 = cowplot::plot_grid(pgrid, leg, ncol=1, rel_heights = c(0.9, 0.05))
```

[image]

### workaround 2

I also tried [this idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54239237/5238559) where only the the density function is in a loop, but then I run into difficulties with achieving a common color scheme (each quantile should be the same color across panels), as the fill "Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (36).".

```
p3 = 
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y))  + 
  facet_wrap(~cut, ncol=5)
for(c in c("Fair", "Good", "Very Good", "Premium", "Ideal")){
  dat_sub = dat[cut==c,]
  p3 = p3 + geom_density_2d_filled(data = dat_sub, 
    # aes(fill=c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.95)), wrong
    breaks = density_quantiles(dat_sub$x,dat_sub$y, c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.95), 100)) 
}
p3 = p3 + geom_jitter(data=dat, size=0.25, color="red", width=0.2)
```

[image]

Any help getting it to work with the function approach or workaround 2 would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could do `  geom_density_2d_filled(breaks = ~density_quantiles(.x,.y, c(0,.25,.5,.75, .95), 100))` following the formula approach you specified above and that gets you closer, but it doesn't equate Q1 for "Fair" with Q1 for "Good" - it plots them as two separate levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to your second "workaround" but using `lapply` to add the `geom_density_2d_filled` layers per facet. To fix the issue with the fill colors I use `after_stat` to convert the default interval labels of the `level`s or bins to a integer representation so that we have the same categories for each layer and hence get the same colors for the quantiles in each facet panel.

```r
library(MASS)
library(terra)
library(ggplot2)

## data
set.seed(4393)
dat <- data.frame(diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ])

library(ggplot2)

qt <- c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.95)

dat_split <- dat |> split(~cut)

ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) +
  facet_wrap(~cut, ncol = 3) +
  lapply(
    dat_split, \(x) {
      geom_density_2d_filled(
        data = x,
        aes(fill = after_stat(
          factor(as.numeric(level))
        )),
        breaks = density_quantiles(x$x, x$y, qt, 100)
      )
    }
  ) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d("Quantiles:",
    labels = scales::percent(qt[-1]), 
    direction = -1
  ) +
  geom_jitter(size = 0.25, color = "red", width = 0.2) +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.75, 0.25))
```

[image]

Comment: nice, that works!